# Assigning an index value to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, indexing

If I have a numpy array, say it contains A, B, C, D. (assume they are pre defined values). But to each of these, I want to assign a number starting from 1 in incremental order. So A gets 1, B gets 2, C gets 3 and D is 4. What is the most efficient way to construct this index assignment within a for loop?

Comment: Sounds like just a second array with the integers that matches the original array one-on-one.

Comment: This is likely an x-y problem, where you try to solve another problem. This structure may solve that, but there may be a better way to solve your actual problem.

Comment: Remember that the indices of your original array are already what you want; except that they start at 0.

Comment: Or you can use e.g. a dict.

Comment: you can use for loop with enumerate

Comment: 'assign a number' is a vague task.  There already is a default indexing starting with `0`..  It's easy to make an equal size array starting with `1`.  There are various structures that can pair that array with the original,  What do you intend to do with such a pairing/?

Comment: @hpaulj with this pairing what I am trying to do is have an easier way of working with a matrix in numpy so that i dont need to manually figure out the positions of  elements, they are already pre set as U, Lf, Ls, I and R will be the row and column index headers of the matrix. if that makes sense?

Comment: pandas is better if yiu want row and column indices.  numpy is more efficient because its indexing is strictly by position, without separate labels arrays to keep track of.

Comment: Consider intended sizes.  A pandas dataframe is basically 2d,  many rows, fewer columns, in effect a collection large time series.  A numpy array is general purpose, multidimensional, and potentially as large as memory will allow.  It's best for math on many numbers in a parallel, all at once.  numpy doesn't help much if you are dealing with a list or dict of just a dozen values or variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop with enumerate like this :

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

dict = {}

for i, element in enumerate(arr):
    dict[element] = i + 1

print(dict)
```

Comment: How would I access those index in this dictionary though?

Comment: Best to avoid `dict` as a variable name, since it's a builtin.